# I am doing asynchronous processing with scala, but it is not displayed

Tags: scala, concurrency

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future
def now() = new java.util.Date();
(1 to 30).foreach(_ => Future{Thread.sleep(2000);println(now)})
```

I am doing asynchronous processing with scala, but it is not displayed. How can I display it in this case?
No Thread.sleep please.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question again when the previous one has already been answered or closed.

Comment: yep, duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74088786/i-cant-display-it-how-can-i-display-it. And this question has been answered in comments.

Comment: To be fair, the original question was not using `Future`, the answer is slightly different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No Thread.sleep please.

Without any `Thread.sleep` at the end of your program, your code will end after the `foreach` terminates and the async tasks pending will be killed. Thus very likely nothing will be printed because it doesn't take 2s to iterate over 30 items.

---

That being said, you could explicitly wait for the async tasks instead. With something like the following:

```scala
val tasks: Seq[Future[Unit]] = (1 to 30)
  .map(_ => Future {
    Thread.sleep(2000)
    println(now)
  })
val tasksMerged = Future.sequence(tasks)
Await.result(tasksMerged, 3.seconds)
```

`Await` will wait for async task passed in parameter to complete for up to the timeout given in parameter.

Comment: What should I do if there is no println in tasks and I want to display all at the end?

Comment: Display what @panda? If you got a `Future[Seq[String]]` you can `tasksMerged.foreach(seq => println(seq))` or something in this spirit.